# Python3 convert json one-line to multi-line format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Who will help me with the code?

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{"entries": [{"attributes": {"cn": ["John Doe"], "lastLogon": ["133137573913265630"], "sn": ["Doe"], "userAccountControl": ["4096"]},"dn": "CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"}, {"attributes": {"cn": ["Jane Doe"], "lastLogon": [], "sn": ["Doe"], "userAccountControl": ["514"]}, "dn": "CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"}]}
```

which I create with the json module

```
for dc in dcList:
        LDAP_HOST = dc['hostName']
        def ldap_server():
            return Server(LDAP_HOST, use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration, get_info=ALL_ATTRIBUTES)
        conn = ldap_connection()
        conn.search(LDAP_BASE_DN, LDAP_OBJECT_FILTER, attributes=user_attr_list)
        
    ### write data from addc to JSON file
        jsonFile = rootPath + dataPath + LDAP_HOST +"-"+ jsonUsersData
        data = json.loads(conn.response_to_json())
        with open(jsonFile, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

I would like the file to look more readable, for example:

```
{
    "entries":
                [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                                        "cn": ["John Doe"],
                                        "lastLogon": ["133137573913265630"],
                                        "sn": ["Doe"],
                                        "userAccountControl": ["4096"]
                                    },
                        "dn": "CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                                        "cn": ["Jane Doe"],
                                        "lastLogon": [],
                                        "sn": ["Doe"],
                                        "userAccountControl": ["514"]
                                    },
                        "dn": "CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"
                    
                    }
                ]
            }
```

and ideally, the file should be converted to the following format:

```
"users":
            [
                {
                    "cn": ["John Doe"],
                    "lastLogon": ["133137573913265630"],
                    "sn": ["Doe"],
                    "userAccountControl": ["4096"]
                    "dn": "CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"
                },
                {
                    "cn": ["Jane Doe"],
                    "lastLogon": [],
                    "sn": ["Doe"],
                    "userAccountControl": ["514"]
                    "dn": "CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local"
               }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json.dump` arguments like `json.dump(data, indent=2)`.

The second ("ideal") format is not a valid JSON, so it's (AFAIK) achievable only using some other string processing methods *(if it's a typo, the JSON format might be valid, however it's not possible to change format using `json.dump` arguments and it will require few lines of Python code in order to change the json structure).*

EDIT: Also there is more possible using `json.dump` options, some sorting etc. See [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Comment: What is not valid in the second case? Do you mean the missing `{` at the beginning and some missing commas? I guess that was just editing errors in the example.

Comment: @ypnos dunno if it's error or not, but the given format was not clear JSON to me `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Anyways, your answer is sufficient. @kubix: It is probably not easy to find a formatter that does the single-line entries for arrays in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below line of code

`json.dump(data, f,indent=4,sort_keys=True)`

Answer (score 0):

you already have a few answers but here is the full python code

```py
import json

json_string='SOME_JSON_HERE'

try:
    parsed_json=json.loads(json_string)
    out=(json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4,sort_keys=False))
    print(out)
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

usa_json_s = str(usa_json)

usa_json_s = usa_json_s.replace(": [{", ": \n [ \n { \n     ")
usa_json_s = usa_json_s.replace(",", ", \n")

there are a few more stringsteps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).